# ReactJS Get Call Returns Entire Array But Not Single Index

Tags: jquery, api, reactjs, get

Currently, I'm able to return the entire $.get call, but when I try to return the first index it doesn't seem to work. Any insight would be appreciated. I'm essentially going to render out the contents of the array down the road, but currently can't seem to get a single index to display while taking in the entire array of objects from the get call.
You can see the entire call in the TableSet component works just fine. 
 You can see the code here as well: http://codepen.io/PizzaPokerGuy/pen/dXgNvQ?editors=0011

```
var TableSet = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
                  return {
                      data: []
                  };
              },

              componentDidMount: function() {
                  $.get("https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent", function(data) {
                      var userInfo = data;
                      if (this.isMounted()) {
                          this.setState({
                              lastGistUrl: userInfo
                          });
                      }
                  }.bind(this));
              },

  render: function(){

  return(<div className="container">
  <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
         <thead>
         <tr>
         <th>#</th>
         <th>Camper Name </th>
         <th>Points in Past 30 Days</th>
         <th>All Time Points</th>
         </tr>
         </thead>
         <tr><td>1</td><td>{this.state.lastGistUrl}</td></tr>
         </table>
         </div>
  );

}
});

var FooterBar= React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (<div id= "footerBar" className ="container text-center"><strong><h4><a href = 'https://www.YouTube.com/CodingTutorials360'>Check out my YouTube Channel: <br/>CodingTutorials360</a></h4></strong></div>);
  }
});

var LeaderBar = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (<div id='leaderBar' className='container text-center'>
            <h1>Leaderboard</h1>

            </div>);
  }
});
var HeaderBar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div id='headerBar' className = 'container-fluid'><img src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/freecodecamp_logo.svg'/></div>
      <LeaderBar />
      <TableSet />
      <FooterBar />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <HeaderBar />, 
  document.getElementById('mount-point'));
```

Comment: Edgesoft that is a jquery call.

Comment: -Edgesoft when I do this it doesn't render the rest of my page.

Comment: How do you now that $get returns then?

Comment: @Edgesoft I can consolelog the value out in the componentdidmount. Also, when I render the entire array of objects it renders just fine. However, when I render out this.state.lastGistUrl[0] nothing is rendered.

Comment: How many times is rendered runed? In TableSet?

Comment: @Edgesoft I'm not sure how to check that, but it renders nothing but a colored background. If you mean does it not render everytime the answer is yes.

Comment: Console.log before return in render method. If only ones. ComponentDidMount did not trigger a reRender

Comment: @edgesoft it seems to render out the object or any other message just fine.

Comment: getInitialState should return lastGistUrl not data

Comment: Sorry removed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var TableSet = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() { 
    return { 
     lastGistUrl: []
    }; 
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.get("https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent", function(data) {        
       if (this.isMounted() && Array.isArray(data)) {
           this.setState({
               lastGistUrl: data
           });
       }
   }.bind(this));
  },

  renderGist: function() {
    if (!this.state.lastGistUrl) {
      return null
    }
    var items = this.state.lastGistUrl.map(function(gist) {
     return (
       <td>{gist.username}</td>
     )
    })

    return (
      <tr>
        {items}
      </tr>
    )
  },

  render: function() {
    return(
      <div className="container">
       <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Camper Name </th>
          <th>Points in Past 30 Days</th>
          <th>All Time Points</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       {this.renderGist()}
      </table>
     </div>
   );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`lastGistUrl` is set to an Object, not an Array. If you want to access a property of the Object, use `lastGistUrl.propName`, otherwise change the `getInitialState` function to tell React to expect an Array rather than an Object.

Comment: getInitialState does not have lastGistUrl but data

Comment: In the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/PizzaPokerGuy/pen/dXgNvQ?editors=0011) that he linked to, lastGistUrl is there, and data is not.

Comment: Then @user2872518 has changed it because we had a chat. Sorry for my reply. Did not check the codepen again after 50 min

Comment: So, I have fixed this and now can get a single index. However, I am getting an error when trying to access a single item such as "this.state.lastGistUrl[0].username" from the json object

Comment: @user2872518 try `this.state.lastGistUrl.username`

Comment: Returns nothing for this value. The api call gets an array of 100 objects. I'm trying to render out just the 1st username from the value. Later I will map it out to do that.

Comment: Then initialState should be an object and return userInfo[0] in componentDidMount. Check that userInfo is an array as well

Comment: Wait, why would it be an object if we are setting the initial state to an array. It is an array of objects. 

This makes no sense as to why this.state.lastGistUrl[0] which with logged out returns

Object {
  alltime: 2050,
  img: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/4639625?v=3",
  lastUpdate: "2016-08-06T21:26:55.006Z",
  recent: 642,
  username: "sjames1958gm"
}

however nothign is returned when console.log(this.state.lastGistUrl[0].username); is attempted.

Comment: @user2872518 On initial render lastGistUrl has no item in array. If you want  it to be array lastGistUrl must be array in initialState and you should check that there is an item in the array on render.

Comment: getInitialState should have lastGistUrl: [] and render should have {this.state.lastGistUrl[0] ? this.state.lastGistUrl[0].username : ''} or better logic by moving it to own function.

Comment: @Edgesoft that still doesnt make sense to me. In the render function it is logging the object with the username within it. However, when I try to log just the username it is does nothing not even an undefined is returned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120331/discussion-between-edgesoft-and-user2872518).